# ServiceStack Webhook + ServiceStack.Webhooks.OrmLite Subscription Store Plugin Issue

Tags: servicestack, webhooks, ormlite-servicestack, git-webhooks

I have enabled Webhook for my ServiceStack project in which I am using ServiceStack.Webhooks.OrmLite OrmLiteSubscriptionStore to store my subscription everything works fine except Delete operation, it gives below error:

```
    {
  "responseStatus": {
    "errorCode": "MissingMethodException",
    "message": "Method not found: 'Int32 ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteWriteExpressionsApi.Delete(System.Data.IDbConnection, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1<System.Func`2<!!0,Boolean>>)'.",
    "stackTrace": "[DeleteSubscription: 6/15/2020 12:42:28 PM]:\n[REQUEST: {id:c42c28e2-f432-40d1-b370-49a5a8506035}]\r\nSystem.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Int32 ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteWriteExpressionsApi.Delete(System.Data.IDbConnection, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1<System.Func`2<!!0,Boolean>>)'.\r\n   at ServiceStack.Webhooks.OrmLite.OrmLiteSubscriptionStore.Delete(String subscriptionId)\r\n   at ServiceStack.Webhooks.ServiceInterface.SubscriptionService.Delete(DeleteSubscription request)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object )\r\n   at ServiceStack.Host.ServiceRunner`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__15.MoveNext() in C:\\BuildAgent\\work\\3481147c480f4a2f\\src\\ServiceStack\\Host\\ServiceRunner.cs:line 133\r\n",
    "errors": []
  }
}
```

Tried everything available publicly including version matching clearing local nuget cache nothing works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have a version mismatch with the version of ServiceStack you're trying to use vs the ServiceStack version that the [ServiceStack.Webhooks.OrmLite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Webhooks.OrmLite) NuGet package is built with.

You should raise an issue with the [jezzsantos/ServiceStack.Webhooks](https://github.com/jezzsantos/ServiceStack.Webhooks) GitHub project to release a new version that targets the latest v5.9.

Otherwise you will need to downgrade to use ServiceStack **v5.5.0** that the NuGet package was built with.